# SQL Server deadlock issue; multiple processes updating same table but different rows

Tags: sql-server, deadlock

I am having issue with my SQL Server 2014 database.

I have database which hold GPS Devices data, around 4000 gps devices uploading data to server and server updating tableA after parsing the data (all data need to be inserted/updated in same table).

For the past week, the database is showing deadlock events in SQL Server Profiler; as per my understanding, multiple device's data being saved in `tableA` is causing these deadlocks.

And also from front end, users are also selecting records from this `tableA` and updating some records (if needed);

I have tried to analyse the deadlock graph but I am unable to understand it,
further would you please guide me how should be the database structure to handle this multiple (4000 processes) insert/update simultaneously.

I have attached the deadlock graph, please advice me how to prevent this deadlock situation.

[DeadLock Graph 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QRnY0.png)

[DeadLock Graph 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hwHS2.png)

[DeadLock Graph 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JB8e2.png)

[DeadLock Graph 4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BujLi.png)

Comment: This could be very difficult to answer without a lot of specialist knowledge about your database. I would look at the other deadlock questions on SO and apply the fixes that other people have suggested and see which help. There are probably some simple design changes to your database e.g. adding the correct indexes but thats very hard for someone else to advise on.

Comment: Are there deadlocks when the user manual updates are not involved? Its going to be a matter of analysing what is inside your transactions - and making sure there are no long transaction windows, or sets of updates on multiple tables that are in different orders. You mention just TableA, but I'm guessing there are a whole lot more?

Comment: Yes, also deadlock occurs when user try to update the tableA from front side application.